# How to execute yanked multi line command in shell within vim

Tags: shell, vim

I have the following `curl` command in a file.

```
curl \
  --request POST \
  https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=eyJhbGci
```

How do I execute the command in bash/zsh shell within `vim`?
I tried to do `:!<C-r>"` (Ctrl + r then ") but it says

```
zsh:1: no match found: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=eyJhbGci

shell returned 1
```

Comment: Try quoting the URL; the `?` causes both shells to treat the URL as a pattern, but only `zsh` treats a failed match as an error. `bash` simply treats the string literally and passes it to `curl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?` is a glob character, zsh is looking for a file named `http://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo` + a single character + `id_token=eyJhbGci` and reporting that there are no matches.

Escape or quote it, any one of

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo\?id_token=eyJhbGci
'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=eyJhbGci'
"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=eyJhbGci"
```

or use `setopt +o nomatch` to make zsh behave like the default in other shells (if no matches, continue with the argument untouched).

Preferably just quote it.

Comment: from the 3, the last 2 of them are exactly the same. None of them will work If there is no indentation before the URL (IDK why but that's how it is). Maybe you can update the answer to include that.

Comment: and you have opened with a single quote and ended with double-quote

Comment: @s1n7ax Typo, I intended to write one line with single quotes and one line with double quotes, but replaced the wrong pair.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use `:help :w_c` to pass arbitrary lines to an external command.

Select three lines and execute via `sh`:

```
vjj
:'<,'>w !sh
```

Execute current line:

```
:.w !sh
```

Execute whole buffer:

```
:%w !sh
```

Execute given range:

```
:12,34w !sh
```

See `:help :range`.